# How to end a Do Loop in an MS Word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've made a macro to change the header color of a document, but when hitting the end of the document - or if there's no remaining header - I'm getting an error.

What I want is after the last header, at the end of the document, to exit my Do Loop.

Here's my code:

```
 Sub Changecolortest5()
'
' Changecolortest5 Macro
'
'
    If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
        ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
    End If
    If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
        ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
    End If
    Do
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Font.Color = 8527984
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.NextHeaderFooter
    Loop
'Exit Header and Footer
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Addressing Headers/Footers optimally doesn't work well with recorded macros, so I'm going to show you a slightly different approach than what you give us. The code below works directly with the underlying *objects* and applies formatting to the `Range` rather than a selection. This is faster and the screen doesn't "flicker".

When working with a group of things, such as Headers, it's more usual to use a For-Each loop to cycle through the group. In this case, Headers are specific to Sections, so you loop the Sections. Something along these lines:

```
Dim doc as Word.Document
Dim sec as Word.Section

Set doc = ActiveDocument
For Each sec in doc.Sections
  sec.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Font.Color = 8527984
  sec.Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Font.Color = 8527984
Next
```

In addition, if you look up the Help topic for Do loops you'll see that they require a *test* to end the loop: `Do While` or `Do Until` or `Loop While` or `Loop Until` a certain criterium is met. I'm pretty sure the code you show us must be giving you an error - when asking questions you should always include *all* relevant information, including any error messages...

Comment: Hi @Cindy thanks for your help what i did in my code is just putting some On Error GoTo so it will continue even having error. can you help me remove the flicker. i cant paste my code because of the character limit. i just paste the one i add    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.NextHeaderFooter
    On Error GoTo Help
   Loop
Help:
      ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
      Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
     End Sub

Comment: your macro is good and its just a blink of an eye. but its colored all of the head i just want to color the first row of the header. like this [Please Click](http://i66.tinypic.com/3038sa9.jpg)

Comment: You can always use the [edit] link below your question to add additional information, such as a picture. I'm on a mobile device at the moment, but will try to find time to follow up with you later today.

Comment: Thanks very much aprriciate if you dont mind kindly look on this. this is the one im working on [Please Click] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37740165/how-to-merge-macro-code-and-to-avoid-flicker-screen)

Comment: @P.Alvis OK, I've changed the code in my Answer to format only the first paragraph in the Header.